# What should be the reply to "Where are you put up?" or "Where do you put up?". Do they both have same meaning?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Someone recently asked me "Where are you put up?".
I assumed that she was asking me about my place of residence.
Is this the correct way to ask someone where they are staying. Are there any other ways in which we can ask someone about their place?
PS: I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expression is ***[to put someone up:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/put-sb-up)***

> to provide someone with a place to stay temporarily:

As in

> - Sally is putting me up for the weekend.

“*Where are you put up*” is an uncommon  usage of the above expression

“Where are you staying?”, would be a more correct and common way to ask.

from [to stay](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/stay):

> to live or be in a place for a short time as a visitor:

as in:

> - I stayed in Montreal for two weeks then flew home.
> - They said they'd stay at/in a hotel.

Comment: So what should I ask if I want to know the someone's permanent place of residence? Where do you live?

Comment: @lea - yes, that’s for a more permanent place of residence.

Comment: is where do you put up same as where are you put up?